# Номер ячейки в Excel 2007

Tags: excel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать автоматическую нумерацию строк в Excel по условию.
Имеем столбец:

```
avto
avto
avto
moto
moto
avia
```

Хочу получить:

```
avto    1
avto    2
avto    3
moto   1
moto   2
avia    1
```

Answer (score 3):

В Excel есть встроенная функция, подсчитывающая количество определенных значений в выбранном диапазоне - *СЧЕТЕСЛИ()*. Например, данные в диапазоне от *А2* и ниже:

```
=СЧЕТЕСЛИ(A$2:A2;A2).
```

Т.к. формула будет протягиваться по строкам, верх диапазона закреплен.
О закреплении можно почитать здесь:
[относительные и абсолютные ссылки](http://user.hashcode.ru/questions/4128/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0-excel)

Из примера не ясно, могут ли значения находиться в разорванных диапазонах, например -

avto
moto
avto
avto

Если нужен подсчет одинаковых значений, расположенных в соседних ячейках (формула в *В2*):

```
=ЕСЛИ(A1=A2;B1+1;1)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Сохранить первый столбец в txt файл. Потом обработать файл скриптом по алгоритму:

- 1 Задать первой переменной значение "avto"
- 2 Задать второй переменной значение 1
- 3 Читать файл построчно и каждую строку сравнивать с первой переменной
- 3.1 Совпадение
- 3.1.1 Присвоить первой переменной текст строки
- 3.1.2 Добавить в конец строки запятую и второю переменную
- 3.1.3 К второй переменной добавить 1
- 3.2 Несовпадение
- 3.2.1 Присвоить второй переменной значение 1
- 3.2.2 Добавить в конец строки запятую и второю переменную
- 3.2.3 Присвоить первой переменной текст строки
- 3.2.4 К второй переменной добавить 1

Файл переименовать в csv и открывать excel. Костыль конечно, но бейсик я не учил и уже, наверное, не выучу. На линуксовом баше оно имеет такой вид :

```
#!bin/bash
a='avto'
i=1
while read line
do
  if [ $line = $a ]
  then 
  echo $line | sed s/$/,$i/ >> result.csv
  i=$(($i+1))
  a=$(echo $line)
  else 
  i=1
  echo $line | sed s/$/,$i/ >> result.csv
  i=$(($i+1))
  a=$(echo $line)
  fi 
done < file.txt
```

Comment: клево, линукс поставить для экселя ))